reduxjs/toolkit@2.2.3 usage of combineSlices
I can't understand how to typing useAppSelector with LazyLoadedSlices:
I have the store
// @shared/redux/store.ts

// comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/combineSlices
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
export interface LazyLoadedSlices {}

// Global reducer for redux
export const rootReducer =
  combineSlices(baseApi).withLazyLoadedSlices<LazyLoadedSlices>();

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware()
      .prepend(listenerMiddleware.middleware)
      /* comment: RTKQ method */
      /* eslint-disable unicorn/prefer-spread */
      .concat(baseApi.middleware)
});

// Try to typing RootState
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;

export const useAppDispatch: () => ThunkDispatch<
  RootState,
  unknown,
  UnknownAction
> = useDispatch;

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;

So, i try to use lazy loaded slice into my component
// @feature/my-component/store.ts

type State = {
  order: 'asc' | 'desc';
};

const initialState = { order: 'asc' } as State;

const slice = createSlice({
  name: baseName,
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // ...
  },
  selectors: {
    selectOrder: (state) => state.order
  }
});

export const { selectors, actions } = slice.injectInto(rootReducer);

// @feature/my-component/my-component.tsx
export const MyComponent = (): React.JSX.Element => {
  const order = useAppSelector(selectors.selectOrder); // <--- Here got an error

  return (
    // ...
  );
};


I got the error:
Types of parameters state and state are incompatible.
Type {   baseApi: CombinedState<{}, 'Dashboard' | 'Widget', 'baseApi'>; }
has no properties in common with type {   'feature/filter-dashboard'?: State | undefined; }

So i confused to redeclare my useAppSeletor to understand LazyLoadedSlices
I try'ed usage of "useSelector" instead of "useAppSelector" and it is work.
But i wanna typesafe for my project.

You were missing one part of the docs - you have to add your lazy loaded slice to the LazyLoadedSlices interface.
In your slice file:
declare module '.' /* or the path to wherever your original LazyLoadedSlices  interface is exported*/ {
  export interface LazyLoadedSlices extends WithSlice<typeof slice> {}
}


Oh, my bad, thank you very much) My eslint is convert all interfaces to type and when i using 'export type LazyLoadedSlice = WithSlices' i would got error
